# Using NV_depth_nonlinear extension on Tegra Devices

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0, nvidia, tegra

Has anyone used this extension successfully? The Khronos spec can be read here: [NV_depth_nonlinear extension](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/NV/EGL_NV_depth_nonlinear.txt)

I have successfully check the extension via EGL config choosing:

```
public class CustomEGLConfigChooser implements EGLConfigChooser {
    private static final int EGL_DEPTH_ENCODING_NV      = 0x30E2;
    private static final int EGL_DEPTH_ENCODING_NONLINEAR_NV = 0x30E3;
    private int[] mValue = new int[1];


    public EGLConfig chooseConfig(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display) {
        // request configs
        EGLConfig[] configs = egl.eglChooseConfig(...);
        // ...

        EGLConfig bestConfig = null;        
        for(EGLConfig config : configs){
            // check for EGL_DEPTH_ENCODING_NV
            egl.eglGetConfigAttrib(display, config, EGL_DEPTH_ENCODING_NV, 0);
            int hasDepthNonLinear = findConfigAttrib(egl, display, config, EGL_DEPTH_ENCODING_NV, 0);
            if(hasDepthNonLinear == EGL_DEPTH_ENCODING_NONLINEAR_NV) {
                // what to do now ???...
            }
        }
        return bestConfig;
    }

    private int findConfigAttrib (EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display, EGLConfig config, int attribute, int defaultValue) {
        if (egl.eglGetConfigAttrib(display, config, attribute, mValue)) {
            return mValue[0];
        }
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

But how do I use the non linear depth extension? Must I use:

```
glBindRenderbuffer(...);
glRenderbufferStorage(...);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to start using the non-linear Z-Buffer of any GPU, you need to enable the extension (as you did in your code) and nothing else.

The non-linear Z-Buffer is handled by the GPU itself and, as often we do not realize, it is used by most of the modern GPUs.

As reported in this interesting article (http://www.sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/love_your_z_buffer.html):

> The Resolution of Z.
>
> What people often fail to realise is that in nearly all machines, the
>   Z buffer is non-linear. The actual number stored in the Z buffer
>   memory is related to the Z coordinate of the object in this manner:
>
> z_buffer_value = (1<
>
> Where:
>
> ```
>  N = number of bits of Z precision
>  a = zFar / ( zFar - zNear )
>  b = zFar * zNear / ( zNear - zFar )
>  z = distance from the eye to the object
> ```
>
> ...and z_buffer_value is an integer.
>
> This means that Z (and hence the precision of Z) is proportional to
>   the reciprocal of the z_buffer_value - and hence there is a LOT of
>   precision close to the eye and very little precision off in the
>   distance. This reciprocal behaviour is somewhat useful because you
>   need objects that are close to the eye to be rendered in great detail
>   - and you need better Z precision for detailed objects.
>
> However, an undesirable consequence of this is that many of your Z
>   buffer's bits are wasted - storing insanely fine detail close to the
>   near clip plane. If you pull the near clip closer to your eye, then
>   ever more bits are dedicated to the task of rendering things that are
>   that close to you, at considerable cost to the precision a bit further
>   out.
>
> It follows that in most cases, flimmering can be greatly reduced - or
>   even eliminated by moving the near clip plane further from your eye.

In my humble experience, I have used successfully the non-linear ZBuffer on TEGRA as I have suggested in this response, hence, I can say it works as stated.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. Right now I have no Tegra device on my hands. I will test the behavior of my z buffer, when I have one in about 3 weeks.

Comment: Hi Maurizio, I'm trying to enable this feature on a Nexus 7 (Tegra 3) tablet but putting it into eglChooseConfig() finds no available configs. In your experience, do you know if this should work? Thanks

Comment: Hi Chris,
I checked my code to remember the way i have done this and what I found is that, in case of TEGRA, I set an additional parameter in the chooseconfig like the following:

     EGL_DEPTH_ENCODING_NV,EGL_DEPTH_ENCODING_NONLINEAR_NV,

where EGL_DEPTH_ENCODING_NV is 
     "private static final int EGL_DEPTH_ENCODING_NV = 0x30E2;"

and EGL_DEPTH_ENCODING_NONLINEAR_NV is:
"private static final int EGL_DEPTH_ENCODING_NONLINEAR_NV = 0x30E3;"

Answer (score 0):

Testing on Nexus 7, I was able to get this to work by adding to the `eglChooseConfig` call:

```
EGL_DEPTH_ENCODING_NV, EGL_DEPTH_ENCODING_NONLINEAR_NV,
```

and by using

`DEPTH_COMPONENT16_NONLINEAR_NV` in place of `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16` for our `glRenderbufferStorage` call.

**Edit:** Actually we don't use a depth buffer for our main egl surface, so only `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_NONLINEAR_NV` was needed.  Also changed `DEPTH_COMPONENT16_NONLINEAR_NV` to `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_NONLINEAR_NV` as it's defined in the NDK .